# Oracle: selective uniqueness index issue with update

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, constants

I have created selective unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fn_unique_idx 
    ON table1 (CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' THEN id ELSE null END,
               CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' THEN name ELSE null END,
               CASE WHEN is_deleted='N' THEN type ELSE null END);
```

So at any point of time I want only one entry with is_deleted 'N' for (id, name, type).

Insertion works fine i.e. it allows to enter mulitple is_deleted 'Y' and thows unique constriant exception when I try to insert with is_deleted = 'N' which is expected.

But when I try to update it is thowing 
oracle error:

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qctVCO : bfc], [1], [0], [1], [871], [1], [2], [875], [], [], [], [] 


SQL : UPDATE table1 set is_deleted = 'Y' where id = 1, name = 'foo' and type =bar';
```

I want to set this current entry as deleted and insert a new entry with updated data and is_deleted = 'N'. This is basically for maintaining the history.

Can someone help me fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

that type of error is an oracle internal error - aka a bug...

what patch version are you on?  perhaps go the the current one just in case.

Comment: Oracle version is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: The only published bug for qctVCO:bfc in 11.1 is 7599848, which relates to selecting from a table with an encrypted column that has an index - fixed in 11.7.0.7 Patch 6 on Windows, and 11.2.0.1. Probably not relevant unless you're using TDE, but I agree with Randy, patch up and if it doesn't go away then raise a SAR with Oracle. I'd still look at Branko's advice though. (And I assume the command and missing quote are transcription errors, and your actual SQL update is valid?)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, you want to be able to have several rows with the same `(id, name, type)`. For one of these rows `is_deleted = 'N'` and for the rest of them `is_deleted = 'Y'`.

Is that correct?

If so, let me offer some ideas:

1. Remove the `is_deleted` field. Instead, have a `version` field and whatever the latest version is, this is the row which is not deleted. The unique constraint/index then naturally covers `(id, name, type, version)`. This can complicate querying though.
2. Introduce 3 new fields: `archive_id`, `archive_name`, `archive_type`. The unique constraint still covers the original `(id, name, type)`. The row is "deleted" by moving values to `archive_*` fields and NULL-ifying the original fields. This should work because tuples that contain all NULLs are not included in the (unique) index.
3. Have a separate table for archival data, without the unique constraint.
4. Maybe use a CONSTRAINT UNIQUE instead of the UNIQUE INDEX?

Also, let us know if there are any referential integrity constraints in play?

Comment: another nice trick is to create a seperate table (is_deleted) and include the primary key columns from the original table, and finally a fine grained security policy that prevents you from seeing rows in the original table when it's primary key exists in the second table. (you can play games with visibility by flipping flags in the second table)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Branko on **point #3**. You could also add START & END dates to this separate table for archival data.